# Probability of a certain sum of $3$ dice given the first die roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

An unbiased die is thrown $3$ times. Given that the first throw is a $5$, find the conditional probability of getting $16$ as a sum.

Here's what I have done. 
$$P(\text{Sum}=16\mid\text{First throw}=5)=\frac{P(\text{Sum}=16\text{ AND First throw}=5)}{P(\text{First throw}=5)},$$

$$P(\text{First throw}=5)=\frac{5\times6\times6}{6\times6\times6}.$$

Now, I have a confusion here in the following regarding choosing the sample space.
To count $$P(\text{Sum}=16\text{ AND First throw}=5),$$ the number of elementary events that are favorable is $2$, and they are $5+5+6$, $5+6+5$: since the first throw is already $5$, there are $2$ choices to make the remaining $11$ so as to make the sum equal to $16$. But what is the sample space? Is it $5\times6\times6$, the number of ways to get as the first throw a $5$ and the remaining two throws out of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Comment: The probability the first throw is a five is not $\frac{5\cdot 6\cdot 6}{6\cdot 6\cdot 6}=\frac{5}{6}$, it is in fact $\frac{\color{red}{1}\cdot 6\cdot 6}{6\cdot 6\cdot 6}=\frac{1}{6}$, exactly as we should have expected if we ignored that there are multiple rolls happening after the first.  Remember there is only one way for the first die to land on a five ignoring the remaining rolls, not five ways.  As for your question of what the sample space is, since you are approaching via the definition your sample space here is of size $6\cdot 6\cdot 6$, same as before.

Comment: Note, your answer should agree with the probability of getting an $11$ as a sum for rolling two dice.

Comment: Hell, My bad! I just realised it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So, Let A be an even of getting sum=16 in three throws and B be an event of getting first throw=5. We want P(A|B), which is = P(A AND B)/P(B), P(B)=1/6 and n(A AND B)=2. P(A AND B)=n(A AND B)/n(Sample space)=2/6*6*6. So, cardinality of sample space here is the same as that of the cardinality of sample space for P(B)? Is this generally true or is specific to the problem? I frequently face difficulty in calculating the cardinality of the sample space of an intersection of sets, since favorable events are relatively easy to calculate given the conditions/informations.

Comment: This is generally true, with the only real exceptions being if it is more convenient to reword the sample space for each of the two events which does happen.  For example in this specific problem, we could have worded the sample space for $P(A)$ as simply being $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the result of the first die roll, instead of as all ways of rolling all three dice, arriving at the calculation of simply $\frac{1}{6}$ instead of the calculation $\frac{1\cdot 6\cdot 6}{6\cdot 6\cdot 6}$.  They both yielded the same answer, but it doesn't help to give ourselves more work than necessary at times.

Answer (score 2):

We know that the first roll is $5$. Thus the second and third die throws must sum to $11$ (because $16 - 5 = 11$).

With six sided dice, there are only two possible combinations for two throws to sum to $11$; that is, the first throw being $5$ and the second throw being $6$, or the first throw being $6$ and the second throw being $5$.

There are $36$ possible combinations and $2$ are valid, meaning the probability will be $\dfrac{2}{36} = \dfrac{1}{18}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering!